# How to put the bottomsheet to the front of the screen?

Tags: react-native, fragment, bottom-sheet, touchableopacity

In ReactNative, the bottomsheet is displayed overlaid on the fragment.
Is there a way to make the bottomsheet rise to the top of the screenenter image description here

The bottom sheet looks opaque as in the picture, so the bottom sheet cannot be touched Please help

The code below is a shortened version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WtHd.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6RD0.jpg)

```
     import React, { FC , Component, useState, useEffect, Fragment,useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from "react"
        import { FlatList, ViewStyle, StyleSheet, View, Platform, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native"
        import {
          BottomSheetModal,
          BottomSheetModalProvider,
          BottomSheetBackdrop,
        } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

        const ROOT: ViewStyle = {
          backgroundColor: DefaultTheme.colors.background,
          flex: 1,
        }

        export const ChecklookupScreen: FC<StackScreenProps<NavigatorParamList, "checklookup">> = observer(function ChecklookupScreen() {
      
          const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

          // variables
          const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);
          
          // callbacks
          const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback((index: string) => {
            LOG.info('handlePresentModalPress', index);
          
            bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
          }, []);
          const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
            LOG.info
            console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
          }, []);

      

          const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              
              key={index + item.inspNo + item.spvsNo}
              //style={listContainer}
              onPress={throttle(() => {
                onClickItem(item.inspNo,item.spvsNo);
              })}
            >
              <View>
                <Fragment>

              
                    </View>
                    <Button icon="magnify-expand"
                            mode="elevated"
                            style={styles.detailButton}
                            onPress={throttle(() => {
                              onClickItem(item.inspNo,item.spvsNo);
                            })}
                            // onPress={() => navigation.navigate("checkdetail")} 
                            >
                    </Button> 
                  </View>

                </Fragment>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );

          const fetchChecklookups = async (offset: number) => {
            LOG.debug('fetchChecklookups:' + offset);
            setRefreshing(true);
            await checklookupStore.getChecklookups(offset)
            setRefreshing(false);
          };

          const onEndReached = () => {
            if (checklookupStore?.checklookupsTotalRecord <= checklookups?.length) {
              LOG.debug('onEndReached555555555');
            } else {
              setPage(page + 1)
              fetchChecklookups(page + 1);
            }
          
          };
          const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState('');

          const onChangeSearch = query => setSearchQuery(query);

          return (
            <Screen preset="fixed" style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background, flex: 1, padding: 10,}}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1,}}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
          
            <Searchbar
                    placeholder="조회조건을 입력해주세요"
                    onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
                    value={searchQuery}
                    onPressIn={() => handlePresentModalPress('touch on')}
                  />
                <BottomSheetModalProvider>
                      <BottomSheetModal
                              backgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}
                              style={styles.bottomSheet}
                              ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
                              index={1}
                              snapPoints={snapPoints}
                              onChange={handleSheetChanges}
                            >
                            <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 50, marginRight: 50, flexDirection: "row"}}>
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
                          <Button 
                          mode="outlined"
                          >소속을 입력하세요
                          </Button>
                      </View>
                      </View>
                    </BottomSheetModal>
                    </BottomSheetModalProvider>

              </Screen>
              )
            })
```

Comment: `BottomSheetModalProvider` needs to be placed at the root of your **app** (NOT at your component's level)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with portal, wrap you bottom sheet to  from another package.